# how connect my own server to a domain?

Tags: dns, centos, reverse-dns

I have a dedicated server in my office and it has a static IP on internet, now  i want to connect this server to a domain and setup mail server on it.
my only problem is how to connect IP and domain?

I have some questions about this but can't find answer by searching, please help me:

- If i had to create my own dns server to handle it? if so how to run dns server
- to create mail server that reliable by gmail and other mail-servers i had to provide RDNS to my server, how?

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have registered a domain already, you add an A record, which specifies hostname and ip address of your server. You don't need to install your own nameservers, if you use services of a DNS hoster. Many registrars, where you can register a domain, also offer such DNS hosting services. However, regardless of who runs the nameservers which are authoritative for your domain, you will still need to add that A record to your zone on the master nameserver. Depending on used service, you may then have to update SOA serial, and issue an update notification to slave nameservers, so they know that they must ask master nameserver for the updated zone - but most DNS hosters do this step automatically.

For reverse DNS, you add a PTR record to reverse zone. The netblock owner is in control of the reverse zone. 
The nameservers authoritative for reverse zone are generally different servers than those you put hostname and ip address of your server on, and you will have to use facilities or cooperation offered by netblock owner.

Comment: thx @Bushmills , can you explain how I can update SIA serial? or give me a link?

Comment: I can't tell you how you would have to update yours. I either use a text editor, and change serial in zone file if the zone is non-dynamic, or, with dynamic zones, let nsupdate take care of it. In case your domain is hosted, your hoster determines how you"d do that - and whether that's necessary at all.